# If statement in PHP

Tags: php

```
$karthik=$_POST['myarray1'];
var_dump($karthik);


if($karthik=="ALTA 3.1-06 (CLTA 123.2-06) - Zoning Classification and Allowable Uses - Improved Land "){
    echo "correct";
}
else {
    echo "incorrect";
}
```

am getting array value as `"ALTA 3.1-06 (CLTA 123.2-06) - Zoning Classification and Allowable Uses - Improved Land"` but the result it is showing as incorrect i want to show it as a correct.

Comment: post exactly the output you got for `var_dump($karthik);`

Comment: Please, take some time to read the FAQ ( http://stackoverflow.com/faq ) to understand how this site works. Use meaningful titles and tags (the question was tagged `javascript` and `linux`... why?).

Comment: Anyway, you have an extra space at the end of the string in the `if` statement

Comment: How is this an wordpress question? Please use better title.

Comment: Without knowing how you post data looks it's hard to say if there is anything "wrong". You could have mixed-up the true/false statements or your post data might be something other than what you expect. Post what you get from a `var_dump($_POST)`. Also, a bit of code from the form where your post data is actually sent from would probably help a bit to.

Comment: possible duplicate of [if condition evaluation in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489870/if-condition-evaluation-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

You got an extra space at the end of your string in the if statement.

Answer (score 2):

because $karthik is an array, $karthik will equal array, you need to specify with a key which value out of the array you would like. I believe the easiest would be to try:

```
if($karthik[0] == "ALTA 3.1-06 (CLTA 123.2-06) - Zoning Classification and Allowable Uses - Improved Land "){
    echo "correct";
}
else {
    echo "incorrect";
}
```

I am not sure if the space at the end is required or not.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that you have a space attached to the end of

```
"ALTA 3.1-06 (CLTA 123.2-06) - Zoning Classification and Allowable Uses - Improved Land "
```

Maybe that's what is causing your error? You can always try trimming your strings.

Comment: I REMOVED THE SPACE BUT STILL IT IS SHOWING "INCORRECT"

Comment: try typing "echo $karthik;" where you have $var_dump and tell me the result.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra space at the end of your "ALTA [...] Improved Land " string.

Comment: i trimmed the string but the result is nill

Answer (score 0):

try removing the extra space at the end of your hard coded string and use [trim](http://php.net/trim) to remove any extra spaces i your POST variable

```
if(trim($karthik)=="ALTA 3.1-06 (CLTA 123.2-06) - Zoning Classification and Allowable Uses - Improved Land"){
    echo "correct";
}
```