# if condition evaluation in php

Tags: php

```
$karthik=$_POST['myarray1'];

if($karthik=="karthik"){
echo "correct";
}
else{
echo "incorrect";
}
```

Here myarray1 is a array variable has got value "karthik" it is showing result as incorrect

Comment: did you try to print $karthik ??
If you did did you get "karthik" ??

Comment: yes after printing that i got value as karthik with string type

Comment: Are there possibly any whitespace/non-printable characters? `var_dump($karthik)` should get you `string(7) "karthik"` - if it shows more characters than 7, you may want to `trim()` your input data.

Comment: yes that also i did but effort in vain

Comment: possible duplicate of [If statement in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6489548/if-statement-in-php)

Answer (score 2):

In the example you have given there is no way that the variable $karthik has the value 'karthik'. Do this before your if statement to confirm.

```
echo '$karthik.... ';
var_dump($karthik);
echo '$_POST["myarray1"]....';
var_dump($_POST['myarray1']);
```

You say

> Here myarray1 is a array variable

This is slightly ambiguous, are you posting this from your page or is this variable coming from somewhere else?

Comment: it is coming from jquery postage

Comment: And what did the results of you var_dump show you?

Comment: @user816829 If you're using Firefox, you can use Firebug or HttpFox (or any other HTTP analyzer) to analyze the contents sent to / received from the server.

Comment: @user816829  Lekensteyn is wise. Follow his advice. The root of this problem is a lack of debugging ability. Good debugging tools are (all these are firefox entensions) Firebug, Firequery, FirePHP, The Console generally (google 'console.log' for starters), Poster, Httpfox. If you don't know how to use these tools or equivalents you're going to have a bad time.

Answer (score 1):

You're suggesting that `$_POST['myarray1']` is an array, this will evaluate to "Array" when used in string context. So, it's obvious that the condition `$karthik=="karthix"` is false, because `"Array"` does not equal `"karthix"`.

If you've a field like:

```
<input name="myarray1[]" value="karthix">
```

you can check whether the field contains the value `"karthix"` by using the [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function for checking whether a string is contained in the array or not:

```
$karthix = $_POST['myarray1'];
if (in_array("karthix", $karthix)) {
    echo "correct";
}
```

Comment: $_POST['myarray1'] doesn't need to be an array, why can't it be a string?

Comment: @kissmyface The name suggests that the variable is an array. I've made it more clear now

Comment: You're probably right you know - there was something slightly fishy about 'Here myarray1 is a array variable' :-)